# FFMPEG exception in debug mode only

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, visual-studio-2012, ffmpeg

So I'm trying to use ffmpeg in c++. My code is like this:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C"
{
#include "libavcodec\avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat\avformat.h"
#include "libswscale\swscale.h"

}

using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "dev/lib/avcodec.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dev/lib/avformat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dev/lib/swscale.lib")

int main()
{
    avcodec_register_all();
    av_register_all();
    char inputFile[] = "video.mp4";
    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;

    if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, inputFile, NULL, 0) != 0) // exception occurs here
    {
        cout << "could not open file"; 
        return -1;
    }

}
```

This code runs in release mode but in debug mode I get the exception at `avformat_open_input`:

> Unhandled exception at 0x0000000074BC3C35 (avformat-55.dll) in
>   ingrain.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

I downloaded the dll's and lib's directely from ffmpeg's site and included them in my visual studio 2012's project.

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__decoding.html#ga10a404346c646e4ab58f4ed798baca32).

```
int avformat_open_input ( AVFormatContext ** ps,
                          const char * filename,
                          AVInputFormat * fmt,
                          AVDictionary ** options 
                        )
```

> Parameters
>
> `ps`: Pointer to user-supplied AVFormatContext (allocated by
>   `avformat_alloc_context`). May be a pointer to `NULL`, in which case an
>   `AVFormatContext` is allocated by this function and written into `ps`.
>   Note that a user-supplied `AVFormatContext` will be freed on failure.

You haven't initialized `pFormatCtx`, either allocate it with `avformat_alloc_context`, or set it to `nullptr` to have it automatically allocated by `avformat_open_input`.